# Is it possible to list all affected rows in a query or transaction in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Scenario: I do some manual SQL commands to fiddle with a database. Something like, `update users set name='Married Name' where id = 123;` to update a user's name to a married name.

I know: this should be something the user can do themselves or there should be an admin interface. It's coming soon, but for the time being, I need to do that manually. Or maybe there's some other maintenance to do on the database.

Ideally, just for sanity checking (did I forget the where clause?) I'd like to say, "how many rows are affected by my current transaction", because I always wrap my write actions in transactions, if for no other reason to provide an o-crap bailout point. If I get "one row", that's fine, and if I get "250 rows", that's a problem and I need to look back.

It's not a replacement for careful work, but I figure I'm bound to make a stupid error once or thrice, so this could help guard against that.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What sql tool you use to send queries to DB? Postgres reports the number of affected rows after every update/insert/delete statement but not every tool displays that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the clause you are looking for is `returning`.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html

I have not tested this, but try:

```
update users set name='Married Name' where id = 123 returning *;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had accidentally left QUIET on in my psqlrc (I \set QUIET 1, but then \unset quiet, which is apparently case-sensitive).

So that gets me the nice affected-rows-count from each command (the above commands would say stuff like "UPDATE 1" or "UPDATE 200" if I messed up).

That said, attaching a `returning *` to the end of my commands as @Andreas suggested seems like a *really* good idea. I fiddled with it, and when I'm doing dangerous stuff, it is great to get feedback about "these are the things you're about to delete, are you sure you don't want to rollback?".

Comment: Do note that you won't see any "side effects" from the update/delete. Cascading FK constraints or triggers could cause more things to happen than the ones that `RETURNING` shows.